# ubuntu server bind issue

Tags: server, bind

vi named.conf

```
    zone "evi.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/evi.local.db";
};

    zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

vi evi.local.db

```
$TTL    604800
evi.local.      IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
                        20180524        ; Serial
                        604800          ; Refresh
                        86400           ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                        604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;
evi.local.      IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
ns1             IN      A       192.168.10.10
www             IN      A       192.168.10.10
@               IN      AAAA    ::1
```

vi rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa

```
$TTL    604800
evi.local.      IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
                20180524        ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;
evi.local.      IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
10              IN      PTR     ns1.evi.local.
```

named-checkzone evi.local evi.local.db

```
zone evi.local/IN: loaded serial 20180524
OK
```

named-checkzone rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa

```
rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa:5: ignoring out-of-zone data (evi.local)
rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa:12: ignoring out-of-zone data (evi.local)
zone rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: has no NS records
zone rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors
```

what am i missing ?? why errors in rev file ??? thanx for your help
i need this for exam... please help

---

vi evi.local.db

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
2018052401      ; Serial
604800          ; Refresh
86400           ; Retry
2419200         ; Expire
604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL

evi.local.      IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
ns1             IN      A       192.168.10.10
www             IN      A       192.168.10.10
```

vi rev.10 file

```
$TTL    604800
@               IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
                2018052401      ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL

        IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
10      IN      PTR     ns1.evi.local.
```

like this ?

Comment: You've failed to create a proper reverse lookup zone.  Technical reasons why you're failing are in my answer, but that's why it's broken.

Comment: Regarding the "Like This": No, the zones are still not correct.  Unless you set `$ORIGIN`, you need to have in the local db for forward lookups `evi.local.  IN SOA ...` and for reverse `10.168.192.in-addr.arpa    IN SOA ...` for the SOA records.  (Then @ should behave; note the `...` means "the rest of the SOA record")

Comment: sorry but i'm not getting it. to bad you cannot upload pictues. what do you mean with $origin ? like this >>> $TTL 604800 rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN SOA ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. ( 2018052401 ; Serial 604800 ; Refresh 86400 ; Retry 2419200 ; Expire 604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL 10 IN PTR ns1.evi.local.  ?? then in the local.db file change the @ back to evi.local. ?

Answer (score 2):

You've got two problems, which ultimately combine to make the third and in turn the errors you're getting:

1. The SOA record in your reverse zone is not set properly, and
2. The A, AAAA, etc. records aren't permitted in reverse DNS zones, which means that
3. Your entire reverse DNS zone file is wrong, which is why `bind9` complains.

`rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa` handles reverse records for `192.168.10.0/24` with the zone name of `10.168.192.in-addr.arpa`.  If I have the addresses 192.168.10.15 assigned to `foo.bar`, and 192.168.10.16 assigned to `baz.foo.bar`, and I want the reverse lookups to reflect this, the records would have to look like this in the zone file:

```
$TTL    604800
10.168.192.in-addr.arpa.      IN      SOA     ns1.foo.bar. root.foo.bar. (
                20180524        ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;
15    IN PTR    foo.bar
16    IN PTR    baz.foo.bar
```

Note that the Reverse Zone takes numeric IP lookups, and has PTR records for the rDNS (reverse DNS) lookups for an IP address to get its hostname.

The equivalent forward-lookup zone for `foo.bar` that'd correspond to the *.foo.bar addresses in the reverse zone would be like this:

```
$TTL    604800
foo.bar.      IN      SOA     ns1.foo.bar. root.foo.bar. (
                        20180524        ; Serial
                        604800          ; Refresh
                        86400           ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                        604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@               IN      A    192.168.10.15
baz             IN      A    192.168.10.16
```

And in your network, if the only 'domain' zone served by `192.168.10.0/24` is `*.foo.bar`, then you would have records in the rDNS which would correspond directly with A records in the forward lookup zone.

---

Judging by your comments, you **know nothing about how BIND works**, and therefore are failing to configure zones.  Other than suggesting you **not** take the exam you're taking, your zone files need to be ***the following, verbatim, as i type them***.  Note that I and others ***hate spoon-feeding users direct answers to questions like these***.  So study these zones below as I wrote them, or you will **never** be able to properly configure `bind9`.  ***You should also learn how BIND9 actually works*** to truly understand what these zones are doing.

For the `evi.local.db` file, use **exactly this**:

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN evi.local.
@       IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
2018052401      ; Serial
604800          ; Refresh
86400           ; Retry
2419200         ; Expire
604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL

@               IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
ns1             IN      A       192.168.10.10
www             IN      A       192.168.10.10
```

For the `rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa` file, use **exactly this**:

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN 10.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
#               IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
                2018052401      ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL

        IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
10      IN      PTR     ns1.evi.local.
```

These zones should work without issue, and solve the issues you're seeing.  **I strongly recommend you study them.**  However, for your exam, they will probably replace the `$ORIGIN` lines with nothing, and then instead of `@ IN SOA ...` you need to replace the `@` sign with the actual zone name (which in these examples is set with `$ORIGIN`).

Comment: `$TTL    604800
rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa             IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
                2018052401      ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL

10      IN      PTR     ns1.evi.local.
`

Comment: @eds *no*, not `rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`, just `rev.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`  The SOA and zone need to match the declaration of the zone name at `zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {` in your config, *not* the filename.

Comment: $TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
2018052401      ; Serial
604800          ; Refresh
86400           ; Retry
2419200         ; Expire
604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL

@       IN      NS      ns1.evi.local.
ns1             IN      A       192.168.10.10
www             IN      A       192.168.10.10 for evi.local.db ??

Comment: reverse lookup file 
$TTL    604800
@               IN      SOA     ns1.evi.local. root.evi.local. (
                2018052401      ; Serial
                604800          ; Refresh
                86400           ; Retry
                2419200         ; Expire
                604800 )        ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.
10      IN      PTR     evi.local.
??

Comment: @eds Since you *obviously* don't know how `bind` zones actually work... I'm going to spoon-feed you the exact zone files you need to use.  Study them.  Failure to study means you will fail your exam on DNS configuration in the most gloriously fiery way possible.

Comment: thank you for this, yes i now that i will need to study, but we have no info from instructor. and are left by are selfs to figure out. now i have an example so i can test if works and work from there. change things and figure out this. thank you for your time. kind regards